# Почему нет выхода за пределы массива

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп

Задание из экзамена:

```
class X
{
public:
    X(int x){cout<<x-1;}
};

template <class T, int d=3>
class Container
{
    T* _arr;
public:
    Container():_arr(new T[d]){}
    void setItemAtIndex(T item, int index){ _arr[index]=item;}
    X getItemAtIndex(int index){ return _arr[index];}
};

int main(){
Container<int>container;
for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
    container.setItemAtIndex(i,i);
    X x = container.getItemAtIndex(i);
}
return 0;
}
```

Нужно написать скомпилится ли программа, если да то какой вывод. Вывод:012.
Я не понимаю одного, когда мы создаем класс Контейнер по умолчанию рамез массива 3,  когда идет цикл в мейне он идет начиная с 1, соответственно когда i=3 функция setItemAtIndex получает (3,3) и кладет 3 в место массиве 3, но разве если массив на 3 элемента последний элемент не должен быть под индексом 2?

Comment: Не важно что написано в коде, который не может компилироваться.

Answer (score 0):

Выход за пределы массива является Неопределенным Поведением. Соответственно отсутствует возможность предсказать, скомпилируется ли программа, и что именно будет результатом ее работы.

Comment: Но тем не менее тут вообще нету выхода за пределы, несмотря на то, что вроде бы элемент кладется под индексом 3

Comment: @YuriyRusanov просто система выделила чуть больше и ошибка сразу не бросается (в глаза) из-за этого. Но это вовсе не значит, что выхода за пределы массива нет. Он есть, просто не проявляет себя, пока.

Comment: @YuriyRusanov *"вообще нету выхода за пределы"* - почему это вдруг? У вас же правильно написано - последний элемент имеет индекс 2, а при обращении к элементам с последующими индексами будет выход за пределе. Заметьте, что судить о том, был ли выход или нет, на основании работы программы вы не можете.

Answer (score -2):

У массивов вида T* проверки на выход за пределы массива нет. За границей массива может лежать мусор, обращение и изменёние которого ни к чему плохому не приводит. При этом программа падать не будет.